# WebBrowser.Source.AbsuloteUri return null, but I initialized the source

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, uri, nullreferenceexception

I have simple window with, let's say, two controls: WebBrowser and TextBox.

```
<TextBox Name="uriTextBox"/>
<WebBrowser Name="webPageWebBrowser"/>
```

and the MainWindow.xaml.cs with the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webPageWebBrowser.Source = new Uri("https://google.com");
        uriTextBox.Text = webPageWebBrowser.Source.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

So, webPageWebBrowser.Source throws an exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser.Source.get returned null.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the source, after it is loaded

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webPageWebBrowser.Source = new Uri("https://google.com");
        webPageWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
    }


private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   uriTextBox.Text = webPageWebBrowser.Source.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

From the documentation:

> Setting the source property causes WebBrowser to navigate to the document specified by the Uri. If the Uri is null, a blank document is displayed ("about:blank").

So I'm assuming that the source is null until it's loaded.